# How can I update specific fields in database by Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

The code below updates all fields of object. How can I update specific fields in a similar way?

```
public void update() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    for (Object object : currentPager.getList()) {
        Book book = (Book)object;
        if (book.isEdit()){
            session.update(book);
        }
    }
    transaction.commit();
    session.flush();
    session.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dynamic_update attribute on your entity:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
    dynamicUpdate = true
)
public class Book implements java.io.Serializable {
```

This will cause only the modified fields to be updated

Comment: Is there a way to ignore some fields when updating? Your way doesn't work for me, because one field of book object has null value. But I need to save the value of the database for this field.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your need. If you are creating a record in the database, and the field is nullable in the DB, then it will be created with a NULL value unless you have assigned some other value to the field in your object. If you are updating a record, then if the object member has been changed to NULL from some other value, then NULL will be saved to the database.